# How can I make better custom dialogs?

Tags: java, android, menu, dialog

I'm creating a game and in it I use a lot of dialogs. The dialogs make up the main menu in a more simple setup then making up an entire activity for it. These dialogs though, they have a grey outline which is really annoying, and in addition when going from one dialog to another, it shrinks down and blows up as one dissapears and another one reappears.

How can I remove the outline and make the transition more smooth? If it is not possible with dialogs, what can an alternative be? I am using custom layouts connected to Java classes that extend [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

**EDIT**

Java:

```
public class MenuDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context con;
    Clicker c;
    public MenuDialog(Context c, Clicker game) {
        super(c);
        this.con = c;
        this.c = game;
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        show();
    }


    Button stat, gem, cash, shop, powerup, settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle sis){
        super.onCreate(sis);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        setButtons();

    }

    private void setButtons(){
        stat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStats);
        gem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGems);

        gem.setOnClickListener(this);
        stat.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bStats:
                StatDialog sd = new StatDialog(con,c);
                sd.show();
                break;
            case R.id.bGems:
                IAPDialog iapd = new IAPDialog(con, c);
                iapd.show();
                break;
            //other buttons

        }
        dismiss();
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/phone_like_bc"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"

        android:layout_marginTop="51dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bStats"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bGems"
            android:background="@drawable/stat_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bGems" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/stats"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bStats"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bStats"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bStats" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/bShop"
            android:background="@drawable/shop"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView17" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/shop"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bShop"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bShop" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gem"
            android:id="@+id/bGems"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/gems"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bPowerUp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bPowerUp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/bPowerUp"
            android:background="@drawable/lightning"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bSettings"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bSettings" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/powerups"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bSettings"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bSettings"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bSettings"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bSettings" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/bCash"
            android:background="@drawable/cash"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text=" " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/cash"
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/bSettings"
            android:background="@drawable/settings"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bCash"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bCash"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bCash" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bCash"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView19" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

There are two more dialog classes both XML and java. I added those two to show that I already know how to add the classes, but I need to know how to remove the outline of the dialog and I need to know how I can smoothen the transition between two dialogs. They have the same background too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DialogFragments instead of Dialogs, they works as Fragments and you can customize them. Read more about the use of Dialog fragments at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

You have a lot of Tutorials to create your own DialogFragments in Google if you don't like the Android Documentation.

Comment: When not dismissing the dialog main, this really looks way better. When pressing the back button on extention dialogs they dismiss so the main one still is there. It really did a lot to change to DialogFragment